# Does assigning an object to other creates a copy?

Tags: c#, object, reference, garbage-collection, dispose

I tried with the below code, I got the output as 1000. I heard assigning object must share the reference instead of copying the entire object memory. Here the result is different.Can anyone help.

```
public aaaaa ad = new aaaaa();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program p = new Program();
    p.fun1();
    p.fun2();
}

public void fun1()
{
    using(smallclass s = new smallclass())
    {
        s.j = 1000;
        ad.fun1(s);
    }
}

public void fun2()
{
    ad.fun2();
}
```

```
public class aaaaa
{
    public smallclass h = new smallclass();
    public void fun1(smallclass d)
    {
        h = d;
    }
    public void fun2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(h.j);
    }
}

public class smallclass:IDisposable
{
    public int j = 9;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Update:
   I expect an object reference exception as the referenced memory is disposed in p.fun1();

Comment: What is your expected output? It's hard to tell where your thinking is wrong when you don't say what you're thinking. The code works fine: expected output is `1000`.

Comment: Question is not that clear. The output 1000 is the expected one. May be telling the output you expected helps in explaining.

Comment: I expecting exception as the output. Because assigning h = d, has to copy the object's reference instead of object's memory. Considering, it just shares the reference and as the object is disposed in p.fun1(), how the result becomes 1000 is a question.

Comment: It copies whatever you're assigning.  In this case, you're assigning a reference.

Comment: am also disposing the memory. hence the reference must be null and it have thrown exception isnt it?

Comment: You're not disposing any memory. You don't understand how `IDisposable` and `Dispose` works. Your `Dispose` method only marks the object as *don't call finalizer on this object when you're cleaning it up* in Garbage Collector (that's what [`GC.SuppressFinalize` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize(v=vs.110).aspx) does). It does not free any memory at all.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek   ok, I miss something there. I will check. Thanks.

Comment: It's depend whether the type is Mutable or Immutable. Mutable cause no new memory location while on the other hand Immutable types creates new memory location and point to that. Different types like DateTime etc are Immutable which mean it's create new memory location.

Comment: @NomiAli Types like DateTime are also not classes but structs.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Even If i use GC.Collect() it still displays 1000 as output. Is there a way to force the garbage collector in dispose method, like Free function in c++

Comment: @TomTom yes of coarse the struct are value types, even if their members are ref type.

Comment: @MuthukumarPalaniappan PLease try a book about C# basics. No, there is no way to free an object. You can force a garbage collection, but that has serious side effects.

Comment: @MuthukumarPalaniappan Calling `GC.Collect()` won't free the object, because there is still a reference to it somewhere in your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an simple example how assinging works

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static smallclass objA = new smallclass();
        private static smallclass objB = new smallclass();

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            showValues();

            objA.value = 1000;

            showValues();

            objB = objA;

            showValues();

            objA.value = 1055;

            showValues();
        }

        private static void showValues()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("objA.value: " + objA.value);
            Console.WriteLine("objB.value: " + objB.value);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    internal class smallclass : IDisposable
    {
        public int value = 0;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            //Here you can remove eventHandlers
            //or do some other stuff before the GC will play with it
        }
    }
}
```

Like you can see

1. first we create 2 objects `objA` and `objB`
   than we show the values like expected they are both 0
2. after that we increase the value of `objA` to 1000
   the value of `objA` a is 1000 and the value of `objB` remains at 0
3. NOW we assingning `objA` and `objB`
   so the value of `objB` got also 1000
4. if we now change the value of `objA` to 1055
   the value of `objB` get also changed 
   because `objB` is no more an separate object it now holds the same
   reference like `objA` does

### EDIT

And now i will show you how you get your Error based on your example

change your `aaaaa class` to:

```
public class aaaaa
{
    public WeakReference<smallclass> h;
    public void fun1(smallclass d)
    {
        h = new WeakReference<smallclass>(d);
    }
    public void fun2()
    {
        smallclass k;
        if(h.TryGetTarget(out k))
        Console.WriteLine(k.j);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR ERRROR ERROR");
    }
}
```

and modify your `static void Main(string[] args)` to:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.fun1();
        GC.Collect();
        p.fun2();

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Ok lets get through the changes

we are using the [`WeakReference<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/gg712738%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  *(you could also use [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.weakreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))*
if the GC now comes across our object he can't find a StrongReference so can Collect it

now to the [`GC.Collect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.gc.collect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) YOU need to call it because it forced the GC to do his work (now at this moment)

and remember like i told you before [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will get called from the GC before he destroys the object (AFAIK) so there is the place to put all the stuff that need to be done before the object will get destroyed

Comment: Good exemplification, I wrote a variety with this and understood different behaviors. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, assingning is not a "new" statement, it copies.... a reference, it does not create a new object. For a class.

For a struct, it does so.

I suggest learning C# by reading the documentation or a book - those basics are normally handled to great detail in those.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. A direction about reading a weak reference or GC.Collect would have helped me even more.

Comment: @MuthukumarPalaniappan No it would not.. With you level of knoweldge the onl thing that helps is erading the C# documentation FRONT TO BACK. Partial wisdom on fundamental levels like that is the source of bad software and awwfull desicions sired on ignorance. You have holes that other people drive trains through. Hugh. Significant. Fundamental.

Answer (score 1):

You will not go far wrong if you think of every reference type variable, field, parameter, array slot, or other such storage location, has holding either "null", or "object #24601" [or some other number].  There are really only a handful things that can be done with references:

1. You may create a null reference
2. You may ask the system to create a new object and return a reference to it
3. You may copy one reference to another
4. You may check whether two references are equal to each other, or whether one is equal to null.
5. You may ask the system to perform some action upon the object *identified by* a reference

If `myCar` is a variable of some reference type, a statement like `myCar.Color = CarColors.Blue` won't affect the variable `myCar` at all.  Instead, it will observe that `myCar` holds [e.g.] "Object #8675309", and then ask the system to access the `Color` property or field of object #8675309.  Conversely, if `otherCar` happens to hold "object #90210", a statement of the form `otherCar=myCar` won't do anything with object #8675309, nor object #90210, but will instead replace the "90210" stored in `otherCar` with "8675309".

Objects are *guaranteed* to exist as long as *any* form of reference to them exists, but if there are two objects which, although referenced by each other, are not referenced by anything else in the universe, both objects may simultaneously cease to exist.  This rule is absolute, but there are a couple of twists: code may request a `WeakReference` to an object; an object is guaranteed to exist as long as a weak reference to it exists, but if the system discovers that no strong references to an object exist, it will invalidate every `WeakReference` to it.  Further, the system keeps a list of all objects that have would like to be notified if they are abandoned.  If the system finds that this list holds the only reference to an object, it will move the object to a strongly-referenced list of objects whose `Finalize` method should run at the first convenient opportunity.  When the object's `Finalize` method is run, the reference will be removed from that latter list.  If no reference to the object has been stored anywhere in the mean time, the object will cease to exist.

Comment: +1 because I could not give +2 :). The first 2 sentences of last para answers my question greatly. Also the case discussed after that in rest of lines are very detailed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced GC.SuppressFinalize with GC.Collect() in dispose function, however this is not freeing the memory.. and am receiving 1000 as a result.

I guess, as it holds other reference(the variable h), GC will not free the memory, even if we invoked it explicit.

So we can very well pass and assign the objects irrespective of the allocated(new) object going out of scope.

Please correct me If i am wrong.

Comment: take a look at my [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21773470/1993545) if you do this changes you get what you where expecting